# Setting up sharepoint rest api as backend in Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, sharepoint-rest-api

We are trying to setup sharepoint rest api in Azure apim backend. We set up the following apim policy. It is receiving the client token, but , not able to successfully execute rest call in the sharepoint. I am not sure whether we are on the right track. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
        <set-url>{{authorizationServer}}</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{
          return "client_id={{clientId}}&scope={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials";

          // For Azure AD v1, try return statement below
          // return "client_id={{clientId}}&resource={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials";
      }</set-body>
    </send-request>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (String)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])</value>
    </set-header>
    <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
    <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
```

Comment: Are you gettting any error?

Comment: Make a call through test console in Azure portal and take a look at trace you get.

Comment: What does "not able to successfully execute rest call" mean specifically? Please provide more details about what needs solving. The goal is that people do not need to guess things about the problem that you already know.

Answer (score 0):

- Before calling backend services we need to initiate a request for which APIM provides [send request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request#send-request) where you can use that in your [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies) along with the [C# expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions).
- Also, you can go through this document which has details about [Access tokens](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/api-management-policy-for-access-token-acquisition-caching-and/ba-p/2191623).
- As you have already generated token just check the app is granted through [enough permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386756)
- For complete details about SharePoint Rest API go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) and this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/727718/how-can-i-connect-sharepoint-rest-api-from-apim-2.html) discussion.