# Sharepoint REST API - How to get Access Token?

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, httprequest

Following [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321532/sharepoint-rest-api-how-to-get-access-token), posted a year ago, Where is the official documentation on how to retrieve an access token? I saw the two answers to the prior question were vastly different in methods. Other APIs I've worked with had a much simpler way to obtain a bearer/access token.

Could *someone currently working with Sharepoint API* provide how they request an access token for requests like this:

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

Comment: I'm new to Sharepoint. Apologies if I am slow to understand what sharepoint add-ins are. Though I think they may be relevant here?

Comment: Does your question have a UI or is it headless?  Are you authenticating against commercial (.sharepoint.com) or government (.sharepoint.us) tenants?  Does the authentication token expire?  Remember, the Bearer token is an ACCESS token, not an AUTHENTICATION token.  How you acquired your authentication token will also affect how you get the access token.  A little more information would help us provide the best possible answer for you.