# Get Azure Authentication token from user/password - no clientId given

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I want to access the sharepoint API and only have my username/password. I dont have an app registration and also not the access rights to create it, which means I dont have a clientID.

How can I get an access token?

Since I am able to access sharepoint from my useraccount, I believe it must be possible witout a clientID. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to obtain an access token, but not without an app registration. Please see this post:
[SharePoint Rest API how to get Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321532/sharepoint-rest-api-how-to-get-access-token)